Fetch data and dynamically show it in the same component?
I give Inertia a try right now and maybe my understanding is not correct or I miss something. I have a Detail component like this. This one has an input text for an api key and a button. Below that I want to render a list of items, when the submit call is coming back with a response.
<script setup>
defineProps({
    connection: Object,
    lists: Array
})

const form = useForm({
    api_key: null,
})

function submit() {
    form.post('/get-lists', {
        only: ['lists'],
    })
}
</script>


<template>
     <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <InputText type="text" v-model="form.api_key" />
        <div v-if="form.errors.api_key">{{ form.errors.api_key }}</div>
        <Button
            :disabled="form.processing"
            type="submit"
            label="Submit"
        />
    </form>

    <template v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id">
        {{ list.name }}
    </template>
</template>

My PHP Controller in Laravel looks like this:
public function getLists(Request $request): Response
    {
        $client = new Client($request->get('api_key'));
        $response = $client->list();

        return Inertia::render('Details', [
            'lists' => $response['lists'],
        ]);
    }

What happens now is that, the request is being made. The data is also displayed, but the route changes to get-lists.
I thought that, when returning the same Component, Inertia detects what has changed and just refreshes the component, and is not performing a reload/redirects.
I thought about returning a json response and handle the data in the onSuccess hook. But this does not work, as Inertia needs a InertiaResponse. In this case I can not built a dynamic SPA. Is my understanding wrong or do I miss something - do I need to use Livewire instead of Inertia to do what I want to do, or using a Axios request with Inertia, to render this list dynamically inside the Vue Component?

The short answer to your question is that for this use case, you should make use of a simple XHR request (using fetch or any library of your choice, like Axios for example) just like you would with any other SPA app.
From the server you would send back json:
public function getLists(Request $request): Response
{
    $client = new Client($request->get('api_key'));
    $response = $client->list();

    return $response['lists']
}

And in the client-side, instead of defining a list prop, use a standard ref and update it with the response:
const lists = ref([])// remove the lists prop
const { data } = await axios.post('/get-lists', yourData)
lists.push(data)

You should use Inertia::render only when rendering a full page component. For example, you might use it when first loading the page or when navigating to a new page.
Sometimes when needed you can even combine one controller that dynamically responds with json or Inertia::render based on the request. A good example is an infinite scrolling implementation, you can have on the first request (when the page loads) Inertia::render and then for the sequel requests just return json:
The controller will look something like this:
public function getLists(Request $request): Response
{
     // XHR request
     $lists = $yourData;
     if (request()->wantsJson()) { 
         return new JsonResponse($yourData);
     }
     // First request
     return Inertia::render('Details', [
         'lists' => $lists
     ]);

}

And then from the client-side you'll send the corresponding pagination params based on the state of the page.
The last example should help you understand more when Inertia::render should be used vs just returning simple json.

Thanks, for the comprehensive answer. This was really helpful. So in my case, I can not use the form Helper from Inertia, right? I need to send the data via Axios and do the error handling etc by myself. So in this case it makes no sense, to use useForm, right?

Correct. It's because you are just adding dynamic data to the page. Usually when doing a traditional server side rendered app (think of Laravel with blade), you would display the saved data on a different page, and here is where Inertia comes in handy, it allows you to navigate without the full page reloads in a SPA fashion, but not when you just want to dynamically fetch data from the server on your current page, then you would do it just as with a standard SPA. I hope this clarifies a bit more.
